# Showing older version of app on play store after uploading latest version?

Tags: android

I uploaded 1.0.2 as a production  in play store but still user got 1.0.1. I didn't  get why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few hours for google play store to update your app after you uploaded an update

Comment: How much time it will take?

Comment: Generally it takes around 8-12 hours.Check your APK status if it is in prod. I am also facing issue, I have uploaded APK 2 days back and still its play store is not showing updated version